# How to upload file by file not in one cycle?

Tags: android

I have an app that uploads selected images to the server.

in one `Activity`, I have a list, to display the image names.
in this list, I have a `ProgressBar`, which indicates the upload method.

I managed to put ProgressBar for every item, but when I click upload, the whole upload session is running, and just the first ProgressBar is moving. when finished, I change the ProgressBar to a success image.

Question:
How to upload file by file, to be able to show every ProgressBar.

Comment: Try base64 encode the image?

Comment: `managed to put ProgressBar for every item`. Ok. Every list view item has its own progressbar.  Then every progress bar is shown. What else? Please explain better your problem as i dont understand it.

Comment: `How to upload file by file`. Why would you do that? I thought your problem was that only one progress bar is moving!?

Answer (score 0):

Open stream for your file, then get total file size. copy data between streams by fixed size buffer and notify your progress bar each time portion of data is copied ( copy data in background and post progress on main thread)